# Numpy Does Not Install

Tags: python, numpy

I’m basically trying to install Pandas, but to do that I’m supposedly supposed to be installing Numpy.

I type this into the terminal:

pip install numpy

And I get an error which basically says I need Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 14.0. After I downloaded it from the link it provided, I have absolutely no idea how to work with it. I’ve tried to use a YouTube tutorial on how to use Visual Studio, but when they create a project I don’t have any of their options. The only option I have is to create a blank solution.

If the rest of the error message is necessary please alert me of that, I’ve only started to work with Python for a couple months, so I’m not very experienced.

Error Message:

```
(venv) C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/1e/ff467ac56bfeaea51d4a2e72d315c1fe440b20192fea7e460f0f248acac8/numpy-1.18.2.zip
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py prepare_meta
data_for_build_wheel C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7lo0j8qw:
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
    Cythonizing sources
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\pc\\PycharmProjects\\Tutorials\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
      libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\pc\\PycharmProjects\\Tutorials\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\pc\\PycharmProjects\\Tutorials\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize PGroupFlangCompiler
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\pc\\PycharmProjects\\Tutorials\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\pc\\PycharmProjects\\Tutorials\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\pc\\PycharmProjects\\Tutorials\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\pc\\PycharmProjects\\Tutorials\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\pc\\PycharmProjects\\Tutorials\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\pc\\PycharmProjects\\Tutorials\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\pc\\PycharmProjects\\Tutorials\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\pc\\PycharmProjects\\Tutorials\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    flame_info:
      libraries flame not found in ['C:\\Users\\pc\\PycharmProjects\\Tutorials\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\pc\\PycharmProjects\\Tutorials\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    running dist_info
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:461: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-az7mvo02\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-az7mvo02\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-az7mvo02\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-az7mvo02\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-az7mvo02\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel C:\
Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7lo0j8qw" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-az7mvo02\numpy
```

Error when upgrading pip:

```
(venv) C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/0c/d01aa759fdc501a58f431eb594a17495f15b88da142ce14b5845662c13f3/pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 2.2MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.0.3
    Uninstalling pip-19.0.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-19.0.3
  Rolling back uninstall of pip
  Moving to c:\users\pc\pycharmprojects\tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg
   from C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\Lib\site-packages\~ip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg
  Moving to c:\users\pc\pycharmprojects\tutorials\venv\scripts\pip-script.py
   from C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-hqx4h1fb\pip-script.py
  Moving to c:\users\pc\pycharmprojects\tutorials\venv\scripts\pip.exe
   from C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-hqx4h1fb\pip.exe
  Moving to c:\users\pc\pycharmprojects\tutorials\venv\scripts\pip3-script.py
   from C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-hqx4h1fb\pip3-script.py
  Moving to c:\users\pc\pycharmprojects\tutorials\venv\scripts\pip3.8-script.py
   from C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-hqx4h1fb\pip3.8-script.py
  Moving to c:\users\pc\pycharmprojects\tutorials\venv\scripts\pip3.8.exe
   from C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-hqx4h1fb\pip3.8.exe
  Moving to c:\users\pc\pycharmprojects\tutorials\venv\scripts\pip3.exe
   from C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-hqx4h1fb\pip3.exe
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 179, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 384, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 53, in install_given_reqs
    requirement.install(
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 910, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 437, in move_wheel_files
    move_wheel_files(
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\wheel.py", line 544, in move_wheel_files
    generated.extend(maker.make(spec))
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 405, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 309, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 245, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 384, in _get_launcher
    result = finder(distlib_package).find(name).bytes
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bytes'
```

Comment: What platform are you on? It sounds as if there is no binary version of NumPy for your platform.

Comment: It would help if you include the error you get. If it's a lengthy error message, start by including the last 20 lines or so.

Comment: I’m on Windows 10.

Comment: Windows 10 should have a binary NumPy version, so you really should include the error message in your question to see what's the actual problem.

Comment: Should I just post it in a comment? This is my first time using this website.

Comment: No, [edit] it into your question, as I mentioned. It'll be unreadable in a comment. Plus, comments are to ask for clarification, but should not contain essential information, which this is. Preferably, format it with a code block, so that the error message is readable.

Comment: What Python version are you on? This sounds a lot like you're still on Python 2, which NumPy and Pandas don't support any more.

Comment: I'm on Python 3. Latest version from like three or four months ago.

Comment: And by the way I edited it.

Comment: Can you update `pip` and see if the error is still there? `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Were you using Python 2 at some time before? Try running pip with `--no-cache-dir` and see if it picks up the pre-built wheel this time.

Comment: I got an error when upgrading pip. I updated the topic.

Comment: I have never used Python 2 before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a couple options:

1) Download the Binary from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

> For projects which don’t provide their own Windows installers (and
>   even some which do), Christoph Gohlke at the University of California
>   provides a collection of Windows installers. Many Python users on
>   Windows have reported a positive experience with these prebuilt
>   versions. [Source](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-scientific-packages/)

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Search for and download:

> numpy‑1.18.2+mkl‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl

Open terminal, activate your env, and install (change the path to where file downloaded):

```
pip install C:\Users\pc\downloads\numpy‑1.18.2+mkl‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl
```

2) Since you are using Windows (like I do), I would highly recommend taking advantage of [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section) distribution of Python.  Will save you a lot of time in the long run.  Basically, it install the binary packages rather than requiring you to compile resources using pip.

Since you are using Pycharm, after you install Anaconda, go back to Pycharm, create a new environment using Conda and then pip install numpy.

3) Try to Compile (Good Luck)